# Querying Hive table while it is being streamed to via apache NiFi

Tags: hadoop, hive, streaming, apache-nifi

I have a hive managed table that is being streamed to via apache NiFi.
When the number records is menial ~10k I am able to run simple queries on the table like count(*) but when the number of records cross that threshold my queries start failing with the error

**Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.FileNotFoundException): File does not exist /delta<..>/bucket<..>**

On the RM UI I could confirm that **compaction jobs are being run on the table**, which seems to be the reason for the missing files.

How can I query a hive table that is being streamed to while compaction is running ?

STACK -

HDP    3.1.0.0
Tez    0.9.1
Hive   3.1.0

Comment: I'm not sure you can, but you can use MergeRecord in NiFi to create larger files to stream into Hive, then compaction should happen less often

Comment: @mattyb thank you for replying. Tried MergeRecord but it has it's own tradeoffs and compaction needs to be run eventually. It is however clearly mentioned in the hive documentaion that compaction runs in the background and doesn't affect concurrent reads/writes 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions#HiveTransactions-Compactor